# How to remove the "TEST" in the given PDF and later saving it using any java library

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I have a pdf where I would like to remove the wordings printed as "TEST" using any java library
Could you please help here.
Please check the attached sample pdf what should be removed.

[image]

Comment: I am unable to attach the sample pdf but please let me know if there is a way

Comment: You can link to a sharehoster. However I'm wondering whether you're trying to create a real invoice by altering a test file.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr: Here I am trying to remove the wordings "TEST" in a pdf. Please refer the image for the same how "TEST" is printed on the PDF. I couldn't able to identify the exact object in java which is referring "TEST'.  We are not trying to make a real invoice here. We have a requirement to compare the two pdfs in our QA environment where this "TEST" is giving a issue in comparison. So trying to remove and compare teh two pdfs

Comment: There are many ways to do the same thing in PDF. It could be text, a transparent image, a vector graphic, an annotation (with these), or a form XObject (with these).

Comment: The "TEST" is being printed on the pdf due to the certificate used while generating the PDF in our QA env. In production it seems like there will be another certificate.

Comment: Please do share an example pdf as described by @TilmanHausherr - you can use e.g. Google drive or Dropbox, create a publicly shared file there, and post the url here.